# ordering a column based on calculated value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have below values in a column

```
    Q1 2018
    Q2 2018
    Q3 2018
    Q4 2018
    feb 2018
    mar 2018
    Q1 2019
    Q2 2019
    Q3 2019
    jan 2018
    sep 2018
    dec 2018
    jan 2019
    feb 2019
    mar 2019
```

I have above values which gets calculated on some parameters. for some data this value comes with month and for some this comes as quarter.

Is there any way to order them using order by when all the values are on the same column, means monthly values and quarterly value both should be sorted.

output should be like

```
Q1 2018
Q2 2018
Q3 2018
Q4 2018
Q1 2019
Q2 2019
Q3 2019
jan 2018
feb 2018
mar 2018
sep 2018
dec 2018
jan 2019
feb 2019
mar 2019
```

Comment: This is a horrendous table design.  You should store this date information in a proper _date_ column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
order by len(col),         -- put the quarters first
         substr(col, 4),   -- order by year
         (case when col not like 'Q%'
               then to_date(col, 'MON YYYY') 
          end),            -- order months by date
         col               -- order quarters by quarter
```